# Converting text to number

Tags: formula, text, convert, number

I am trying to create a new field and convert a text to a number but am getting this error

`(Error: text__c may not be used in this type of formula) when using this formula (Value(text__c))`.

The `text__c` is also an external id, so I am not sure if that is the problem. I mainly need a number version of `text_c` field so I can sort it properly in a table. What should I do to resolve the error? I checked all of the records for the field and there is no letters...

- `text__c` is a text field under the same object i am creating a new field for. it is not encrypted

Comment: Custom fields end with two underscores + c (`__c`) while your question only indicates that there is one underscore. Double check to make sure your formula is using two underscores. Also, if this field is from a managed package, you'll need to add the package namespace + two underscores at the beginning (so it could be something like `MyCoolPackage__Text__c`)

Comment: Also, please check to see what the field type of `text__c` is and [edit] your question to add that information. LongTextArea, and encrypted text fields cannot be used in formulas ([see relevant help page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.formula_field_limits.htm&type=5)).